# n-2 n n+2 only one of it is divisible 3 this can similarly extended to 5 where difference were 4 .I want to ask is there a generalized statement

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please bear with me .
I am new .
All in question.
I haven all information  in the question.
n is integer.
I am new but I observed so asking.
n-2 n n+2 only one of it is divisible 3 this can similarly extended to 5 where difference were 4 .I want to ask is there a generalized statement

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148506/discussion-on-question-by-paramtatva-n-2-n-n2-only-one-of-it-is-divisible-3-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Take as an example the sequence k+b1, k+b2, k+b3, k+b4, k+b5 and k+b6. Calculate b1 mod 5, b2 mod 5, …, b6 mod 5. If there are five different results then one of the numbers is divisible by 5, no matter what k is. If there is no number say with bi mod 5 = 4, then no number is divisible by 5 if k=1, 6, 11, 16, 21 etc.

Comment: For 5 difference is 4